# efficient algorithm to check if there exists a row and a column with same values?

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to solve this problem using the least running time.
If we're given a 2D array, we need to return x if there exists a row where all values equal x, and there is a column where all values equal x.
For example, for the following 2d array,

> 0 3 1
>
> 2 3 1
>
> 1 1 1

we are supposed to return 1 since the last row and last column are all of same value 1. If no such number exists, we can return -1.

I know there are many ways to solve the problem and most of them are of O(n^2), I'm wondering if there is an efficient way(i.e O(n)) to find such value. (where n represents the number of cells in this array)

Comment: How do you measure the complexity? I can think of an O(n) approach, where n is the number of values in the matrix, that is rows*columns. That is, with one scan of the entire matrix, from top-left to bottom-right, compute whether there's a row or a column with the same value. It's not clear if you consider this O(n), or not.

Comment: n is the number of cells in this 2d array, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, you clarified that you consider O(n) to be the number of values in the 2D array.

I'll outline the approach in pseudo-code, which you can translate to either Java or C++, whichever is your preference. Your question is tagged with both, and the pseudocode is trivial enough to be directly translatable into either C++ or Java. Or Perl. Or Python...

## Part 1

Let's start with the first, easy step, how to check whether there's any row that contains the same value. The pseudocode for this is elementary:

- start with the 0th row, n=0
- check if matrix[n][0] through [n][m-1] (where m is the number of columns in the matrix) contain the same value. If so, you found it.
- otherwise, increment n, to go to the next row, until you reach the bottom of the matrix.

You should be able to understand that. This is basic, elementary "Computer Science 101" stuff.

## Part 2

Now, let's modify this pseudocode to simultaneously check the columns as well. Modify the above pseudocode as follows.

- Create two one-dimensional vectors, call the first one `top_values`, or something, whose size is `m`, the number of columns in your matrix. Call the second one `flags`, it's a vector of boolean flags, also their size is `m`.
- When you scan the 0th row, in the pseudocode given in the first part, copy the values from the 0th row, into `top_values`. That is, copy `matrix[0][x]` into `top_values[x]`. Also set `flags[x]` to `true` (you can initialize all `flags` to `true` even before you scan the 0th row, it doesn't matter).
- When you scan each one of the remaining rows, using the pseudocode given in Part 1, compare `matrix[y][x]` (where y is the row# you're scanning) against `top_values[x]`. If they are not the same, set `flags[x]` to false.
- At the end of the pseudocode from part 1, check your `flags` vector. If any value in it is still true, there's a column in your matrix whose values are the same.

Your homework assignment is to make a slight tweak to the above pseudocode to also tell you which value is the same, in some row or column.

Comment: looks good, thank you! However, this pseudo code only checks for columns. Should I declare another two one-dimensional vectors and do the same thing again to check for rows?

Comment: No, reread: part 1 checks the rows: "check if matrix[n][0] through [n][m-1] (where m is the number of columns in the matrix) contain the same value. If so, you found it." While checking each row, you're simultaneously checking the columns, using the pseudocode for part 2.